# Expected value using the Kronecker Product

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I am reading a book and the author provides the following relationship without much explanation:

$$E(x'Axx'Bx) = E(\operatorname{tr}(x'Axx'Bx)) = E[\operatorname{tr}(\left(x' \otimes x'\right)\left(A \otimes B\right)\left(x \otimes x)\right)]$$

I understand the introduction of the trace since $x'Axx'Bx$ is $1\times1$, but I do not understand the third part.

I guess the underlying question is this:

How do I show that $x'Axx'Bx = (\left(x' \otimes x'\right)\left(A \otimes B\right)\left(x \otimes x)\right)?$

Comment: Probably the identity $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ is being used here (and $A$ and $B$ need not be _square_ matrices for that to hold).  But then there's also something going on with identities involving Kronecker products. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note: $1\times1$ is standard usage; $1x1$ is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's not clear that you need to show $x'Axx'Bx = \left(x' \otimes x'\right)\left(A \otimes B\right)\left(x \otimes x\right)$; it would certainly be enough to show that those two matrices both have the same trace. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also $(x'\otimes x')(A\otimes B)(x\otimes x) = (x'Ax)\otimes(x'Bx)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think that is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(x' \otimes x')(A \otimes B) (x \otimes x) = (x'Ax) \otimes (x'Bx).
$$
The expression on the right is a $1\times1$ matrix whose only entry is the scalar $(x'Ax)(x'Bx)$.