# Expectation of quartic form for multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, normal-distribution

I am reading the 2012 version *The Matrix Cookbook*. On Page 43, Section 8.2.4, “Mean of Quartic Forms”:

---

[image]

---

there is a formula that really confuses me:

$$E[x^TAxx^TBx]=Tr[A\Sigma(B+B^T)\Sigma]+m^T(A+A^T)\Sigma(B+B^T)m+(Tr(A\Sigma)+m^TAm)(Tr(B\Sigma)+m^TBm)$$

I do not check formulae of $E[xx^Txx^T]$, $E[xx^TAxx^T]$, or $E[x^Txx^Tx]$ in Cookbook, as they are the special cases of this one. Note that $x\sim N(m,\Sigma)$.

**My question is how to prove it?**

---

The following is my attempt:

Suppose consider the simpler situation: a quadratic form with $A$, $B$ symmetric. I use the same technique appeared on Page 11 of Seber and Lee's book "Linear Regression Analysis" [image]to re-organize these two quadratic forms, then

$E[x^TAxx^TBx]=E\Big\{[(x-m)^TA(x-m)+2m^TA(x-m)+m^TAm)]
*[(x-m)^TB(x-m)+2m^TB(x-m)+m^TBm)]\Big\}$

$=E\Big\{(x-m)^TA(x-m)(x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big\}+E\Big\{(x-m)^TA(x-m)m^TBm\Big\}+E\Big\{m^TAm(x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big\}+E\Big\{m^TAmm^TBm\Big\}+2E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)m^TBm\Big\}+2E\Big\{m^TAmm^TB(x-m)\Big\}+2E\Big\{(x-m)^TA(x-m)m^TB(x-m)\Big\}+2E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)(x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big\}+4E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)m^TB(x-m)\Big\}$

in which the fifth and sixth items are zeros and the first four items can be further rearranged such that they equate $(Tr(A\Sigma)+m^TAm)(Tr(B\Sigma)+m^TBm)$ by the fact $E\Big\{(x-m)^TQ(x-m)\Big\}=Tr(Q\Sigma)$

The last item can be reduced if we notice $(scalar)^T=scalar$:

$E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)\cdot m^TB(x-m)\Big\}=E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)\cdot (x-m)^TBm\Big\}=m^TAE\Big\{(x-m)\cdot (x-m)^T\Big\}Bm=m^TA\Sigma Bm$

Consequently, (**This is my detailed question, how to show it?**) it suffices to show that the seventh and eighth items are equal to the first item in RHS of the initial formula, that is,
$2E\Big\{(x-m)^TA(x-m)m^TB(x-m)\Big\}+2E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)(x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big\}=Tr[A\Sigma(B+B^T)\Sigma]=2Tr(A\Sigma B\Sigma)$

I searched it in this website, the link is useful:
[Expected value using the Kronecker Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562769/expected-value-using-the-kronecker-product)

The RHS of my above equation, by the formula $Tr(ABCD)=vec(B^T)^T(A^T\otimes C)vec(D)$ can be re-written as:

$Tr(A\Sigma B\Sigma)=vec(\Sigma)^T(A\otimes B)vec(\Sigma)$

The LHS, by the link, by the fact $x\otimes y=vec(yx^T)$ for two column vectors $x$ and $y$, and by $scalar=Tr(scalar)$, are equivalent to:

$E\Big\{(x-m)^TA(x-m)\cdot m^TB(x-m)\Big\}+E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)\cdot (x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big\}=E\Big\{\Big((x-m)^TA(x-m)\Big)\otimes\Big(m^TB(x-m)\Big)\Big\}+E\Big\{\Big(m^TA(x-m)\Big)\otimes\Big((x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big)\Big\}=E\Big\{\Big((x-m)^T\otimes m^T\Big)\Big(A\otimes B\Big)\Big((x-m)\otimes(x-m)\Big)\Big\}+E\Big\{\Big(m^T\otimes (x-m)^T\Big)\Big(A\otimes B\Big)\Big((x-m)\otimes(x-m)\Big)\Big\}=E\Big\{vec\Big((x-m)m^T+m(x-m)^T\Big)^T\Big(A\otimes B\Big)vec\Big((x-m)(x-m)^T\Big)\Big\}$

In normal distribution assumption, $vec(E[(x-m)(x-m)^T])=vec(\Sigma)$. Therefore it seems to be really near the final equating relation (it ought to be):

$vec(\Sigma)^T(A\otimes B)vec(\Sigma)=E\Big\{vec\Big((x-m)m^T+m(x-m)^T\Big)^T\Big(A\otimes B\Big)vec\Big((x-m)(x-m)^T\Big)\Big\}$

**Who can help me prove the above equation?** Or **are there any mistakes in derivations before?**

=============================

Here is my second trial:

Inspired by Seber and Lee's book again, on the same page 11,[image] **who can help me expand $E[x^TAxx^TBx]$  into such coordinate forms to get same solution?** though I estimate the working time is huge.

**A natural question** is, based on my first attempt, how to coordinately expand

$2E\Big\{(x-m)^TA(x-m)m^TB(x-m)\Big\}+2E\Big\{m^TA(x-m)(x-m)^TB(x-m)\Big\}=Tr[A\Sigma(B+B^T)\Sigma]=2Tr(A\Sigma B\Sigma)$

from one side then simplified to the other side? It's relatively easy than expanding $E[x^TAxx^TBx]$ for sure, but how to expand $Tr(A\Sigma B\Sigma)$? There are 4 matrices rather than vectors.

==============================

**My last question**: are there any books which not only collect matrix formulae but provide proofs and solutions as well? I need your recommendation!

Honestly thank you in advance!

Comment: About last Question: Pls refer to the book: J. R. Schott, Matrix analysis for statistics, 3rd Ed, John Wiley & Sons, Inc.(2017). Th11.23 p.481-2.

Comment: @JGWang Thank you sooo much!! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: You are welcome, @Royun.

Comment: I added my second answer to address the question of calculating the expectation of product of three quadratic forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A, B$ are real matrices (not necessarily symmetric).

We may express $x = m + \Sigma^{1/2}y$ where $y\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$.

For convenience, denote $C = \Sigma^{1/2}$. Note that $C$ is real symmetric.

Using $4ab = (a + b)^2 - (a - b)^2$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[x^\mathsf{T}Ax x^\mathsf{T}Bx]
&= \frac{1}{4}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}(A + B)x)^2] - \frac{1}{4}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}(A - B)x)^2]\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Px)^2] - \frac{1}{4}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Qx)^2]
\end{align*}
where $P = \frac{A + A^\mathrm{T}}{2} + \frac{B + B^\mathsf{T}}{2}$ and $Q = \frac{A + A^\mathrm{T}}{2} - \frac{B + B^\mathsf{T}}{2}$,
and we have used $x^\mathsf{T}Ax = x^\mathsf{T}\frac{A + A^\mathsf{T}}{2}x$.
*Note*: $P, Q$ are both symmetric.

*Fact 1*: Let $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$.
Let $S$ be a given real symmetric matrix. Then:
(1) $\mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}Sy)^2] = 2\mathrm{tr}(S^2) + [\mathrm{tr}(S)]^2$;
(2) $\mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}Sy)y] = 0$.
The proof is not difficult. I gave a proof of (1) before. See:
[Expectation of product of quadratic forms in Gaussian distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583603/expectation-of-product-of-quadratic-forms-in-gaussian-distribution)

Using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Px)^2]\\
  =\, & 
 \mathbb{E}[((m + Cy)^\mathsf{T}P(m + Cy))^2]\\
 =\,& \mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy
 + 2m^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2]\\
 =\, & \mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy)^2]
 + \mathbb{E}[(2m^\mathsf{T}PCy)^2] + (m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2 + \mathbb{E}[4(m^\mathsf{T}PCy) m^\mathsf{T}Pm]\\
 &\quad + \mathbb{E}[4(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy)m^\mathsf{T}PCy]
 + \mathbb{E}[2(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy)m^\mathsf{T}Pm] \tag{1}\\
 =\,& 2\mathrm{tr}[(C^\mathsf{T}PC)^2] + [\mathrm{tr}(C^\mathsf{T}PC)]^2 + 4m^\mathsf{T}PC C^\mathsf{T}Pm + (m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2\\
&\quad + 2m^\mathsf{T}Pm\,\mathrm{tr}[C^\mathsf{T}PC] \\
 =\,& 2\mathrm{tr}[P\Sigma P \Sigma] + [\mathrm{tr}(P\Sigma)]^2
 + 4m^\mathsf{T}P\Sigma P m + (m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2
 + 2m^\mathsf{T}Pm\,\mathrm{tr}[P\Sigma]
\end{align*}
where in (1) we have used $y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy = \mathrm{tr}[C^\mathsf{T}PCyy^\mathsf{T}]$, and $\mathbb{E}[yy^\mathsf{T}] = I$.

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{E}[x^\mathsf{T}Ax x^\mathsf{T}Bx]\\
 =\,& \frac12 \mathrm{tr}[P\Sigma P \Sigma] - \frac12 \mathrm{tr}[Q\Sigma Q \Sigma]
 + \frac14 [\mathrm{tr}(P\Sigma)]^2 - \frac14 [\mathrm{tr}(Q\Sigma)]^2\\
 &\quad + m^\mathsf{T}P\Sigma P^\mathsf{T}m - m^\mathsf{T}Q\Sigma Q^\mathsf{T}m + \frac14 (m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2 - \frac14 (m^\mathsf{T}Qm)^2\\
 &\quad + \frac12 m^\mathsf{T}Pm\,\mathrm{tr}[P\Sigma] - \frac12 m^\mathsf{T}Qm\,\mathrm{tr}[Q\Sigma]\\
 =\,& \frac12\mathrm{tr}[(A + A^\mathsf{T})\Sigma (B + B^\mathsf{T})\Sigma] + \frac14\, \mathrm{tr}[(A + A^\mathsf{T})\Sigma]\mathrm{tr}[(B + B^\mathsf{T})\Sigma]\\
 &\quad + m^\mathsf{T}(A + A^\mathsf{T})\Sigma (B + B^\mathsf{T})m
 + \frac14\, m^\mathsf{T}(A + A^\mathsf{T})m m^\mathsf{T}(B + B^\mathsf{T})m\\
 &\quad + \frac14\, m^\mathsf{T}(A + A^\mathsf{T})m \, \mathrm{tr}[(B + B^\mathsf{T})\Sigma]
 + \frac14\, m^\mathsf{T}(B + B^\mathsf{T})m \, \mathrm{tr}[(A + A^\mathsf{T})\Sigma]\\
 =\,& \mathrm{tr}[A\Sigma (B + B^\mathsf{T})\Sigma]
 + m^\mathsf{T}(A + A^\mathsf{T})\Sigma (B + B^\mathsf{T})m\\
&\quad
 + (\mathrm{tr}[A\Sigma] + m^\mathsf{T}Am)(\mathrm{tr}[B\Sigma] + m^\mathsf{T}Bm).
\end{align*}

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

*Remark*: In my second answer, we evaluate the expectation of product of three quadratic forms.

> **Problem**: Let $x\sim \mathcal{N}(m, \Sigma)$. Let $A, B, C$ be given real symmetric matrices.
> Find $\mathbb{E}[x^\mathsf{T}Ax x^\mathsf{T}Bx x^\mathsf{T}Cx]$.

Using
$$abc = \frac{1}{24}[(a + b + c)^3 - (a + b - c)^3 - (a - b + c)^3 - ( - a + b + c)^3],$$
we have
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}[x^\mathsf{T}Ax x^\mathsf{T}Bx x^\mathsf{T}Cx]\\[5pt]
=\,& \frac{1}{24}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Px)^3]
- \frac{1}{24}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Qx)^3] - \frac{1}{24}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Rx)^3] - \frac{1}{24}\,\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Sx)^3]
\end{align*}
where $P = A + B + C, ~Q = A + B - C, ~R = A - B + C, ~S = -A + B + C$.

We may express $x = m + \Sigma^{1/2}y$ where $y\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$.
For convenience, denote $C = \Sigma^{1/2}$. Since $\Sigma$ is symmetric, $C$ is also symmetric.

*Fact 1*: Let $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$.
Let $M$ be a given real symmetric matrix. Then:
(1) $\mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}My)^2] = 2\mathrm{tr}(M^2) + [\mathrm{tr}(M)]^2$;
(2) $\mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}My)^3] = 8\mathrm{tr}[M^3] + 6\mathrm{tr}[M^2]\mathrm{tr}[M] + [\mathrm{tr}(M)]^3$;
(3) $\mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}My)y ] = 0$;
(4) $\mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}My)^2y ] = 0$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

Using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{E}[(x^\mathsf{T}Px)^3]\\
 =\,& \mathbb{E}[((m + Cy)^\mathsf{T}P(m + Cy))^3]\\
 =\,& \mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy
 + 2m^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^3]\\
 =\,& \mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^3]
 + \mathbb{E}[(2m^\mathsf{T}PCy)^3]\\
 &\quad + \mathbb{E}[3(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2\cdot 2m^\mathsf{T}PCy]\\
 &\quad + \mathbb{E}[3(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)\cdot(2m^\mathsf{T}PCy)^2]\\
 =\, & \mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^3]
 + \mathbb{E}[3(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy + m^\mathsf{T}Pm)\cdot(2m^\mathsf{T}PCy)^2]\\
 =\,& \mathbb{E}[(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy)^3]
 + (m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^3 + \mathbb{E}[3(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy)^2m^\mathsf{T}Pm]\\
&\quad
 + \mathbb{E}[3(y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy)(m^\mathsf{T}Pm)^2]
  + \mathbb{E}[12 y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}PCy \cdot y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}Pmm^\mathsf{T}PCy]\\
 &\quad + \mathbb{E}[12 m^\mathsf{T}Pm\cdot y^\mathsf{T}C^\mathsf{T}Pmm^\mathsf{T}PCy].
\end{align*}
The left is smooth.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*: Let $M = U\mathrm{diag}(d_1,d_2, \cdots, d_n)U^T$ be the eigendecomposition.
Let $z = U^Ty$. Then $z$ is a random vector with i.i.d. entries distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.
Note that $\mathbb{E}[z_i^6] = 15$, $\mathbb{E}[z_i^4] = 3$ and $\mathbb{E}[z_i^2]=1$.
We have
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[(y^TMy)^3] &= \mathbb{E}[(z^T\mathrm{diag}(d_1,d_2, \cdots, d_n)z)^3]\\
 &= 6\sum d_i^3 + 9(\sum d_i)(\sum d_i^2)
 + 6\sum_{i < j < k} d_i d_j d_k\\
 &= 8\mathrm{tr}[M^3] + 6\mathrm{tr}[M^2]\mathrm{tr}[M] + [\mathrm{tr}(M)]^3
\end{align}
where we have used the Newton identity
$$\sum_{i < j < k} d_i d_j d_k = \frac{1}{6}(\sum d_i)^3
- \frac{1}{2}(\sum d_i)(\sum d_i^2) + \frac{1}{3}\sum d_i^3.$$