# Expectation of product of quadratic forms with noncentral Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with independent entries distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, 1)_{i=1\ldots n}$.  Let $A, B$ be two $n \times n$ symmetric matrices.  I would like to find the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[ (x^T A x) (x^T B x)\right]$.

There is a related [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3583603/737314) for the simpler case $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $\mathbb{E}\left[ (x^T A x) (x^T B x)\right]=\operatorname{Tr}(A)\operatorname{Tr}(B)+2\operatorname{Tr}(AB)\;.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ (x^T A x) (x^T B x)\right]=2\operatorname{Tr}(AB)+4\mu^TA B\mu+(\operatorname{Tr}(A)+\mu^TA\mu)(\operatorname{Tr}(B)+\mu^TB\mu)$$
and the derivation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4247240/737314).